# Как собрать linux программу из исходников, под Windows

Tags: linux, windows, makefile

Собственно проблема в том, что нужно собрать игровой движок из исходников под Windows. **Вопрос в том что для этого нужно?** Там есть пакеты установки для старых MSVC 7.1 но у меня возникла с ним проблема, решил все собирать из исходников. Cкачал .zip движка. Там лежат make файлы. Так вот как эти make файлы собрать под виндой?

Comment: Во-первых - обзавестись кросс-компилятором

Comment: @AseN minGW подойдет? только почему то он у меня с ошибками установился

Comment: @user1, если нет самоцели собрать именно из win, то __проще__ будет поставить виртуалку и собрать под ней... обычный mingw не подойдёт — нужен тулчейн под целевую платформу, а не нативный, т.е. GNU'тый триплет должен выглядеть как `x86_64-[pc-]linux-gnu`... кроме того нужно окружение POSIX — называется cygwin... с большой долей вероятности тулчейн нужно будет собрать самому, обычно это делается с помощью специальных скриптов — `crosstool`... Но если поднимается вопрос «как эти make файлы собрать», то я бы не рекомендовал сразу лезть в эти дебри, а для начала просто собрать под виртуалкой...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо!